# IE hosted .net user control using an unmanaged dll

Tags: .net, internet-explorer

What's a good way for an IE hosted .net user control (e.g., < object classid="myctrl.dll#init">) to pull down an unmanaged dll for it to use?

For Click-once, this is easy with a manifest, but ie hosted controls don't get installed in the click-once app cache and instead run out of the download cache.  Copy the dll there? Or into the temp directory?

Added: I'm fine with full trust.  The reason for using .net is the better security model over active-x (more kinds of evidence)

Answer (score 1):

I'd be surprised if it was possible to do this, because it would be a massive security hole. Native code can only run at full-trust, so loading a new native COM object requires that the object is signed, that the CAB it is downloaded in is also signed, and that the class (once registered) registers appropriately - and the user gets appropriate warnings to ensure that they only run controls and components that they trust.

.NET code is allowed to circumvent some of these rules because it is verified, runs under a virtual machine and is sandboxed.